# NPoco with StructureMap best practices

Tags: structuremap, npoco, mediatr

I'm setting up NPoco for dependency injection on a Web API + MVC 5 project (using StructureMap) and I'm not sure what the best practice is for managing the database connection. Should I use a singleton, or a per-request scope, something else? The database isn't really being used by the API/MVC controllers themselves, instead it is ultimately being injected into Mediatr CQRS handlers.

Currently I'm using a setup class

```
public static class DbFactory
{
    public static DatabaseFactory Factory { get; set; }

    public static void Setup()
    {
        Factory = DatabaseFactory.Config(x =>
        {
            x.UsingDatabase(() => new Database("con"));
            //x.WithFluentConfig(fluentConfig);
            //x.WithMapper(new Mapper());
        });
    }
}
```

which is configured with StrucureMap like this

```
// called from global.asax

DbFactory.Setup();

var container = new Container(cfg =>
{
    // ... other stuff

    cfg.For<IDatabase>().Use(() => DbFactory.Factory.GetDatabase());
});
```